# Making origo in the middle of the plot, can't make grid show

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make grid in my plot, i have other simpler plots where i manage to show grids, but not in this plot:

```
%The AXES command selects the set of axes to plot in,
axes(handles.viewCAM_handles.axes_accVelRatio);
% Plot velV and accV ratio with centered x and y axis
[AX] = plot(velV, accV);
grid on;
set(AX, 'LineWidth', 2);
xlabel('Velocity');
ylabel('Acceleration', 'Color', 'b');
xMax = max([max(velV) abs(min(velV))]);
yMax = max([max(accV) abs(min(accV))]);
if xMax >= 1
    xMax = ceil(xMax);
else
    xMax = round(xMax*10)/10;
end
if yMax >= 1
    yMax = ceil(yMax);
else
    yMax = round(yMax*10)/10;
end
axis([-xMax xMax -yMax yMax]);
y=get(gca,'ytick');
x=get(gca,'xtick');
hold on
Lx=line([x(1) x(length(x))],[0 0]);
Ly=line([0 0],[y(1) y(length(y))]);
set(Lx,'color','k');
set(Ly,'color','k');
for i=1:length(x)
    plot(x(i),0,'kx');
    text(x(i),-.01,num2str(x(i)));
end
for i=1:length(y)
    plot(0,y(i),'kx');
    text(-0.5,y(i),num2str(y(i)));
end
grid on;
set(gca,'yticklabel',[],'xticklabel',[],'ytick',[],'xtick',[]);
```

I'm setting origo in the middle of the plot and i draw lines for that, i think the problem has something to do with that. Any ideas?

I have tried putting "grid on" in other places in this code but i can't manage to show grid.

Comment: running your code with random numbers for velV and accV results in a perfect plot with a grid.  What values do you use? Did you try to restart matlab?

Comment: since i don't have access to your handle variable i skipped the first line: *axes(handles.viewCAM_handles.axes_accVelRatio);*. I guess that could be the source of the issue

Comment: I also use random numbers, i don't think it has anything to do with velV and accV. 
I have restarted matlab several times.
I plot something else both before and after this code in other axes, i need the first line i think? :/

Comment: I just tried en debug the code, i put a marker at this line(the last):                                                set(gca,'yticklabel',[],'xticklabel',[],'ytick',[],'xtick',[]);

before this line there where grid in the plot, but after the grid disappeared?

Sorry for messy answer but i don't know how to make a new line.

Comment: Do you get a correct result if you skip the first line? If thats the case there's something special with the axes...

Comment: But i can't skip the first line? Then how should i do so i plot in the right axes. And like i wrote in my last comment, the grid is showing before the last line.

I tried writing this last in my real code:

grid(handles.viewCAM_handles.axes_posVelMA, 'on');
grid(handles.viewCAM_handles.axes_accJerkMA, 'on');
grid(handles.viewCAM_handles.axes_accVelRatio, 'on');

The grid for the two first axes showed but still not the last one which is the same at in my posted code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the grid lines are related to the x and y ticks of the axis.
So you could either change the line where you delete the ticks:

```
set(gca,'yticklabel',[],'xticklabel',[],'ytick',[],'xtick',[]);
```

to solely clear the labels

```
set(gca,'yticklabel',[],'xticklabel',[])
```

or you have to plot grid manually using lines (see http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102945-how-can-i-specify-the-spacing-between-minor-tick-marks-and-minor-grid-lines-in-my-figures-in-matlab).

Comment: Thanks! Actually i just noticed this myself but i didn't know how to fix it, but your code works, so thanks you for the help!